# Does Xcode 4 have keyboard shortcuts for Replace & Find Next / Previous?

Tags: xcode4, keyboard-shortcuts

Does XCode 4 have keyboard shortcut for the two menu options: Edit > Find > Replace and Find Next / Previous?

If not, (1) why not, (2) how do I create them, and (3) which key combinations do you recommend for the shortcuts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As for Find next/Find previous, you should be able to use standard `Cmd-G` and `Cmd-Shift-G` Mac shortcuts.

But the keyboard shortcut for Edit > Find > Replace doesn't seem to be provided by default.  However, you can set up one if you go to XCode 4 Preferences (Cmd-,) and then click **Key Bindings**.  There are options available for Replace, Replace All as well as Replace and Find Next.

Answer (score 49):

As for Find & Replace, they are provided by default now (version 4.2.1):

**Find & Replace**: `Cmd + Option + F`
**Find & Replace in Workspace**: `Cmd + Option + Shift + F`

Comment: This needs to be the selected answer. Easy and provided by default within Xcode.

Answer (score 5):

You can do that by

Find & Replace: **Cmd + Option + F**
Find & Replace(in Workspace): **Cmd + Option + Shift + F.**

Also you can change this control as per your preference by following these steps:
 1. Xcode > Preferences
 2. Select Key Bindings
 3. Search for command you want to replace and then add a suitable combination.

Refer to the attached Image.[image]

Hope it helps. All the best